# sql server compact installed but i can't find the provider

Tags: windows-ce

i have sql server compact installed in my computer (version 3.5 and 4)

but i can't find the provider [Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5 or] [Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.4]

installation : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CGIKuMl3CwR2dNWXhrbkx4Mk0/view?usp=sharing

providers : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_CGIKuMl3Cwa2VqUncwdm56aWM/view?usp=sharing

1000 thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I got it 100% but where do you want to use the provider name?

Comment: to be able to use this connexion string : Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=myPath\myData.sdf;

Comment: Can you try using this: `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: i'm using vb 6.0 :-(

Answer (score 0):

so

I dont find "Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5" in the sql server providers list
or in ODBC providers but if search it with regedit i found it in then key_classes_root so i try to connect with the vb6 program by :

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim MyConnObj As New ADODB.Connection
   MyConnObj.ConnectionString "Provider=Microsoft.SQLSERVER.CE.OLEDB.3.5;Data Source=c:\articles.sdf;"
   MyConnObj.Open
End Sub
```

and it works very well :-)